# Правильное структурирование кода

Tags: php

Не понимаю как лучше написать код. Что есть

```
if (empty($referral)){
               if ($numrowlogin==0){
                if ($numrowemail==0){
                    require_once 'GoogleAuthenticator.php';
                    $ga = new PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator();
                    $secret = $ga->createSecret();
                    if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `user` (`login`, `password`, `mail`, `status`, `last_act`, `reg_date`,`secret`) VALUES ('$login', '$password', '$mail', 'false', $tm, $tm,'$secret')")){

                        $valid_sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE login='".$login."'");    
                        $valid_row = $valid_sql->fetch_assoc();
                        $id_act = $valid_row["id"];
                        $ref = $ref.$id_act;
                        $mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET Referral = '$ref' WHERE login = '".$login."'");
                        $messageEmail = $mess." <a href=http://mysite.com/activate.php?login=".$login."&id_act=".$id_act.">link</a> ".$mess1. $mess2.'<b>' . $ref .'</b>'.' '.$mess3;


                        if ($resultEmail = mail($mail, $title, $messageEmail, $headers)){
                            $message = 'You win!';
                            $color = 'green';
                            $out = array(
                                'message' => $message,
                                'color' => $color
                            );

                            header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
                            echo json_encode($out);
                            die;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $message = "Failed to insert data information!";
                        $color = 'red';
                        $out = array(
                            'message' => $message,
                            'color' => $color
                        );

                        header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
                        echo json_encode($out);
                        die;
                    }
                }    
                else {
                    $message = "That Email already exists! Please try another one!";
                    $color = 'red';
                    $out = array(
                        'message' => $message,
                        'color' => $color
                    );

                    header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
                    echo json_encode($out);
                    die;
                }
            }
            else {
                $message = "That Login already exists! Please try another one!";
                $color = 'red';
                $out = array(
                    'message' => $message,
                    'color' => $color
                );

                header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
                echo json_encode($out);
                die;
            }
        }
        else {

        }
        }
```

Суть вот в чем, при регистрации пользовали заполняют форму, и в форме есть поле referral code. Мне нужно обработать это поле таким образом, что если поле пустое, то все данные просто вставляются в БД и пользователю на почту приходит письмо(это как раз реализовано в коде выше), но если поле не пустое, то мне нужно сравнивать его с определенными значениями из БД и уже потом принимать решение: записывать пользователя в БД или же вывести ошибку, что реф код неверен. Проблема состоит в том, что я не понимаю как лучше обработать условие, когда поле для ввода кода не пусто, без повторной вставки огромного куска кода, который я привел выше(в том случае, если код действителен и пользователя нужно добавить в БД).

Comment: Вынести повторяющийся код в отдельную функцию и вызывать её. А вообще можно переменную - "накопитель" сообщений.  В проверках складывать сообщения туда. Если count этой переменной в итоге больше 0 - то выводить код со всеми текстами ошибок

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть сравнение с нулем. Сделайте метод и вынесите в файл. Также и с константами и сообщениями. В коде вы их будете не раз вызывать, поэтому выносить в отдельное(цвета сообщения).